# Output JSON object in node js using express

Tags: json, node.js, express

This is my first time using Node and I am using the express framework. I am trying to output a json object when on the "calendar" page (seen in main.js). When I run the router (main.js) I get this error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/Macbook/Desktop/node/views/('calendar.ejs')'

Basically I want to output my JSON object defined in main.js into my html file. Can someone please explain to me why the server cannot find the calendar file. It can find index.ejs but not calendar. And is this the right way to do what I want to achieve?

Below is the directory structure I have setup:

```
-------node_modules
-------routes
-------------main.js
-------views
------------calendar.ejs
------------index.ejs
-------package.json
-------server.js
```

This is my server.js code:

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();

require('./routes/main')(app);
app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

var server=app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("We have started our server on port 3000");
});
```

This is my main.js code:

```
module.exports=function(app){

    app.get('/', function(req,res){
        res.render('index',{title:"Home page"});
    });

    app.get('/calendar',function(req,res){
        res.json({"foo": "bar"});
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess.

First you set the `GET /calendar` route with `require('./routes/main')(app);`.

Then you overwrite the `GET /calendar` route with `app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');`.

You need to choose whether the `GET /calendar` returns rendered HTML or the JSON data.

Comment: require('./routes/main')(app); Defines where our router is and app.set('views',__dirname + '/views'); defines where our HTML files are.

How do these two overwrite each other? It's all in the setup process.

Comment: HTML files are also routes. Each HTML file will create a new route in your app. You have `calendar.ejs` file in the folder, it will create/overwrite the `GET /calendar` route.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand your point. What is being overwritten?
Doesn't the GET /calendar call the calendar.ejs file?

Maybe explaining and giving me a correct way to do this will help me understand better what you are saying. Please keep in my mind that I am new to nodejs. I have just read the documentation.

Comment: The `app.set('views', ...` line will internally call `app.get('/calendar',...`. As the result, your previous call `app.get('/calendar',...` inside the `main.js` will not matter any more. It will be erased.

Comment: ok so your saying that defining the views folder and calling the get method is the same thing?
Then how come the index ejs file shows up fine when I call it using /get in my main js?

Comment: When browser calls `GET /` you render the `index` file. See your `main.js` lines 2 and 3. But when the browser calls `GET /calendar` you do not get to your `res.json()` at all, instead the express app renders the `calendar.ejb` for you.

Comment: How does GET /calendar end up rendering my calendar.ejs when I do not call render I call JSON?

Then how do I output a JSON object {"foo": "bar"} when I go to the calendar page?

Comment: EJS does this for you automatically per each file in your `/views` folder.

Comment: Ok thanks. So the ultimate question here then is how do I output a JSON object {"foo": "bar"} when I go to the calendar page?

Comment: That's a different question. Post a new question with great details, not just one liner in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note :

Since your view files are of `.ejs` extensions so you can comment below line.([documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.engine))

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

It is convention to pass the `app' reference to routers after you have set all the configurations, [middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html) order matters when working on ExpressJS.

### server.js

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
require('./routes/main')(app);
var server=app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("We have started our server on port 3000");
});
```

### main.js

```
module.exports=function(app){
    app.get('/', function(req,res){
        res.render('index',{title:"Home page"});
    });
    app.get('/calendar',function(req,res){
        res.render('calendar',{"foo": "bar"});
    });
}
```

Comment: To clarify- You removed this line app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile); because all my html files were ejs?

And my question is how can I output the JSON object {"foo": "bar"}

Comment: You have to render your JSON data in `calendar.ejs`. If you are facing any problem there then update your post with same. When you are using EJS templates then why again you need HTML files. EJS will take care of all the display logic, you just have to follow proper syntax.